# How to delay system shutdown in windows through a console application?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, console-application

I have a running application and the user has given command for shutting down the system but I want to postpone the shutdown till the time my application is running. After completion of application's work the system should shut down .

Comment: so you want this done without modifying the application code?

Comment: Use SetConsoleCtrlHandler to get a callback at shutdown.  Options to delay shutdown are very limited, you have to be quick.

Comment: No, i want to add this code in my application only,,,,

Answer (score 3):

It depends which version of Windows you're talking about.  With Windows XP, there are messages like WM_QUERYENDSESSION that you can respond to to block shutdown.  (Since you're a console app, you'd probably need to spawn off a little window app to do this while the console application is still running.)

But Vista made it hard for applications to block shutdown. (Microsoft claims that can't do it at all, but I've certainly seen Visual Studio 2010 manage to do it.)  You can delay shutdown for about five seconds (but remember that there may be many other apps trying to do a bunch of stuff during the same five seconds).  At that point, the user gets a UI that shows all the apps that haven't properly shutdown.  With Vista+, you can call [`ShutdownBlockReasonCreate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376877%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to let the user know why it's a bad idea to interrupt your application, but that doesn't actually stop the user from doing so.

Here's the entry point into MSDN for understanding how to cope with [shutdown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376882%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

When windows is shutting down is sent WM_QUERYENDSESSION and application sendback TRUE or FALSE depended on current state.
About this message i found it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms700677(v=vs.85).aspx

maybe its helps you

Comment: This is useful for a Windows application, but not for a console application.

Comment: There's nothing stopping a console application from creating a hidden window on another thread for this purpose.